# How to use a Python Variable in HTML code?

Tags: python, html

I have a String variable(name) that contains the name of the song.
(**Python**)

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BYIKEH0RCQ")
name = yt.title   #Contains the title of the song
```

Here is my **HTML** code for website to download the mp3 song:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="Sample.mp3" download="Song_name"><button>Click here </button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code, I'd like to use the exact title of song as the name of the file when its been downloaded from the user.
I want to use the **name** Variable from Python in place of **Song_name** in HTML code.

Please suggest me any possible way in order to make this work.

Comment: Python has lots of string formatting methods that allow you to substitute the value of a variable into a string. Pick one and use it.

Comment: E.g. f-strings, the `%` operator, the `str.format()` method.

Comment: ...and please don't build products to pirate music. Lots of users here don't like helping people break the law / usage agreements / etc.

Comment: Use triple quotes for the multi-line HTML string.

Comment: @Xitiz I added php , so that if there's any method we can do this using php.

Comment: @Chris I am a school student and I don't know much about that Law .
Is it really illegal to make mp3 songs available for download ??
Then why do we have Pytube Library in Python which can be used to download Videos from youtube.
So , does that mean ?? All the Sites like "Savefromnet" and "yt2mp3" are all illegal ???

Comment: "Is it really illegal to make mp3 songs available for download?"—laws aren't global, but _yes_: piracy is definitely against the law in many jurisdictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try try this:

```py
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BYIKEH0RCQ")
name = yt.title
HTML=f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="Sample.mp3" download="{name}"><button>Click here </button></a>
</body>
</html>
"""
with open("test.html","w") as f:
    f.write(HTML)
```

This will put title of song in download attribute. If you want you may put it anywhere. Just don't forget to use `f""` and `{variable}`.

Comment: Okayy , but then How do I deploy that HTML code when the program is running ??

Comment: What are you using to do deploy?

Comment: I hav'nt planned which service to use to deploy the website !!But at this  moment I want to run the HTML file locally. How do I run the Html code when it is stored in a variable in python ??? ( I am using Pycharm)

Comment: @ChiragSingh check last edit. You can open that html file in browser and you will see title in download attribute!

Comment: You have to think about the flow here.  This Python code will run on your web server.  What's going to trigger that?  Will the user be opening some web page?  If so, then this code will need to be part of a web server application, like Django or Flask (or CGI).  That opening trigger will cause your script to generate HTML back to the user's browser, where he can take the next step.

Comment: @TimRoberts OP already told that OP Hasn't planned that yet and now just want to run it locally in HTML file.